# "Explizites Einverständnis" gegenüber "implizites Einverständnis"

Tags: meaning

In einem elektronischen Formular beschreibe ich, wie die Daten verarbeitet werden. Am Schluss steht dann: *"Durch das Absenden ... erklären Sie sich **explizit** mit der beschriebenen Verarbeitung einverstanden."*

Ich habe im Duden und an anderen Orten über die Bedeutung von *explizit* und *implizit* nachgelesen, konnte aber kein Beispiel für meine Anwendung finden und bin darum immer noch unsicher, ob da nicht *implizit* stehen müsste.

Wäre entsprechend als Titel des Absatzes "Explizite Einverständniserklärung" oder "Implizite Einverstänsniserklärung" richtig?

Comment: In der DSGVO wird für sensible Daten (also die "besonderen Kategorien" nach Art. 9) eine "ausdrückliche Einwilligung" gefordert. Ansonsten ist, glaube ich, immer nur von "Einwilligung" die Rede, die damit auch konkludent sein könnte. Vielleicht wäre es besser, sich diesen Begriffen zu orientieren.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man könnte davon ausgehen, dass der Nutzer mit dem Absenden des Formulars offensichtlich mit der Datenverarbeitung einverstanden ist. Sein Absenden *impliziert* also die Datenverarbeitung. Ohne die Datenverarbeitung ergibt das Absenden des Formulars sonst keinen Sinn.

Sagen wir mal, die Daten könnten optional auch veröffentlicht werden. Dann muss der Nutzer aber unbedingt sein Einverständnis dazu geben, es muss *explizit* erfolgen.

In deinem Fall gibt der Nutzer also *explizit* sein Einverständnis mit der Datenverarbeitung (eine bewusste Handlung), durch das Absenden gibt er es außerdem *implizit*. Für etwas das er anhaken kann, ist deine Variante mit *explizit* also richtig. Könnte er es nicht anhaken, wäre *implizit* richtig.

Das Datenschutzrecht in Deutschland ist eine komplexe Angelegenheit. Mein Beitrag soll dabei keine rechtliche Auskunft darstellen.

Randnotiz: Zu *implizit* ist das Verb *implizieren* gebräuchlich, diese Analogie ist bei *explizit* aber sehr ungewöhnlich.

Answer (score 1):

Meiner (nicht juristisch geprüften) Meinung nach hängt das davon ab, ob in der vorigen Beschreibung schon erwähnt ist, dass der Benutzer sein Einverständnis erklärt. Wenn ja, ist es explizit (es steht ja da), wenn nicht, wird es aus dem Absenden des Formulars geschlossen. Das wird durch [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/implizit) gestützt, wo **implizit** definiert ist als:

> mit eingeschlossen, mit enthalten, aber nicht ausdrücklich gesagt [...]

Typischerweise ist der Unterschied zwischen explizit und implizit größer, was man aus an einer Formulierung sieht wie:

> Durch das Benutzen dieser Seite erklären Sie sich mit ... einverstanden.

Das ist das klassische Beispiel für eine implizite Erklärung.